# Firefox html5 video rewinds instead of playing

Tags: firefox, video, html5-video, webm

I am using video tag on my website. It works with every major browser, but I am running into issues with Firefox.

When I tap on the play button video scrolls to the end of video!

In order to start the video I need to rewind video to position other than start and than click on play.
Weird. 
I tried to set initial position of video to 1s but it didn't help.
I still need to scroll it manually.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

```
<video width="80% height="80%" controls id="video1">
          <source src="videos/<cfoutput>#getVideo.URL#</cfoutput>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="videos/<cfoutput>#getVideo.URL#</cfoutput>.ogv" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="videos/<cfoutput>#getVideo.URL#</cfoutput>.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
          Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>
```

Javascript:

- V I  D E  O  */

  function setupVideo(){
      if(!myVideo){
          console.log("Setting up video");
          myVideo=document.getElementById("video1");
          timeElapsed = 0;
          timer;

  ```
      myVideo.addEventListener("play",videoStarted,false);
      myVideo.addEventListener("pause",videoPaused,false);
      myVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata",videoLoaded,false);

          console.log(" Video Element is: "+myVideo);

  }
  else{
      console.log("Video Was Already set");
      playPause();
      }
  ```

  }

  function playPause()
  { 
      if (myVideo.paused) 
           myVideo.play(); 
      else 
          myVideo.pause(); 
  }

  function videoLoaded(e)
  {
      console.log(" Video Loaded ");
      myVideo.currentTime = 1;
  }

  function videoStarted(e)
  {
      console.log("Video Started");
      //start the timer
      timer = setInterval(videoPlaying,1000);
  }

  function videoPlaying(){
      timeElapsed ++;
      console.log("Video Playing "+myVideo.currentTime);

  ```
  if(Math.ceil(myVideo.currentTime)== 10)
  {
      console.log(" it reached 10  now display quiz");
      playPause();

  }
  ```

  }

  function videoPaused(e)
  {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("Pause");
  }

Comment: Can you clean up the source code indenting a little bit, please? I tried but the code thwarted me somehow and I didn't want to inadvertently edit your code. Basically, highlight block of text and select code indent ("{}" icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WebM or OGV video may have negative or invalid timestamps.  Some software produces video that starts at a time slightly less than zero, particularly if the audio and video frames are not aligned to start at the same time.  (That is, the video may start slightly before 0 and the audio may start at 0.)

If the video is produced with `ffmpeg`, try using the option `-avoid_negative_ts 1`.

If you have the [mkvtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) package installed you can view the timestamps in a webm file with the command `mkvinfo -s` *file*.webm.

Comment: Thanks!
It looks like a video issue.
I used miro video converter.
How can I check if the timestamp is correct?
In other words is there a way to validate the video?

Comment: @Janusz You can view webm timestamps with `mkvinfo -s` *file*.webm (I just added this to the answer).